# How to open this documents using HyperLinkField in a GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am trying to develop a page called Useful Library that will contain many things such as useful presentations and pdf documents. I have a folder in the Server called **(Useful Resources)** and I put all those useful presentations and documents in it. I have the following table in my database:

```
UsefulResources Table: ID, Category, Title, URL, Uploaded Date, Hits
```

The reason of designing this table is to organize the resources. I want now to be able to browse or download these documents. ***For Example, I have presentation called (AP Presentation) that has:
***ID = 5 and URL = AP Prsentation.pptx******

*My ASP.NET code:*

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID,URL" 
                                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Useful Resources/URL={0}" 
                                DataTextField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
```

I have a problem with this part and I don't know how to fix it to be able to open or download this presentation, **so how to do that?**

And for your information, **the page called (Library.aspx)** and I don't have any code-behind

**UPDATE:**

The link that I have right now is the following:
pmvt/msa/pssp/Useful%20Resources/ID=5

*By the way, this is an intranet web-based application so you will not be able to access it using this link.*

And I am getting the following error:
[image]

**UPDATE #2:**
Here's my ASP.NET code with SqlDataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Sql_Reports" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Title], [URL], [UploadedDate] FROM [UsefulResources] WHERE ([Category] = @Category) ORDER BY [UploadedDate] DESC">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label1" Name="Category" PropertyName="Text" 
                                Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="Sql_Reports" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
                        Width="100%">
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title">
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" Width="100px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="URL" 
                                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Useful Resources?URL={0}" 
                                DataTextField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="UploadedDate" DataFormatString="{0:MMM yyy}" HeaderText="UploadedDate" 
                                SortExpression="UploadedDate">
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" Width="100px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                        </Columns>
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

I am still getting the link as ***pmvt/msa/pssp/Useful%20Resources/?URL=Electrical%20safety.ppt***. What I should do to remove ***(?URL=)*** from that link in order to get the link working.

**UPDATE #2:**

Here's the script for create the table in the database with its data:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UsefulResources]    Script Date: 08/06/2012 07:08:15 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsefulResources](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Category] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [URL] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [UploadedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Hits] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UsefulResources] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[UsefulResources] ON
INSERT [dbo].[UsefulResources] ([ID], [Category], [Title], [URL], [UploadedDate], [Hits]) VALUES (1, N'PowerPoint Presentations', N'PMOD', N'Electrical safety.ppt', CAST(0x0000A0A000000000 AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[UsefulResources] ([ID], [Category], [Title], [URL], [UploadedDate], [Hits]) VALUES (2, N'Word Documents', N'Fire Drill Evaluation', N'Fire Drill Evaluation.docx', CAST(0x0000A0A300000000 AS DateTime), 1)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[UsefulResources] OFF
```

Comment: I do not understand what is your problem, what is your error.

Comment: can you tell what can be the value in URL?

Answer (score 0):

A 404 error (as you can see) means that the web server cannot find the page to which the link is supposed to point. The problem may be the Useful%20Resources/ID=5 part of the url.

Generally parameters are passed as key=value pairs after a question mark at the end of the url like this Useful%20Resources?ID=5. This is not always the case (especially in MVC applications) as you can change your site's routing data to return virtually any page from a given url, but I would suggest that you verify that bit first. Once you get rid of the 404 error then take a look at any further problems you may have.

Comment: I am sure that the problem is with this part `Useful%20Resources?ID=5`. **So how to get this link correct?** I am using ASP.NET Webforms. Also, I don't know how to use the ID for getting the link in this part of the URL.

Comment: I am still getting this link: pmvt/msa/pssp/Useful%20Resources/?ID=1. It should be converted to pmvt/msa/pssp/Useful%20Resources/AP Presentation.ppt

Comment: Not sure if you understand the concept of a format string. Basically  the {0} is replaced by a variable... in your case it's being replaced by a weird url... you need to find out where the ?ID=1 is coming from and write your code such that it is replaced with the name of the file that you wish to serve to your user.

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think the white space between `Useful` and `Resources` causes this error. Correct the address to the source file and try again:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="URL" 
                                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}" 
                                DataTextField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am still getting the same error even with changing the name of the folder itself.

Comment: Please try this and tell me about result: <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID,URL" 
                                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Useful_Resources/{0}" 
                                DataTextField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />

Comment: It doesn't work. Also, I got the following link: pmvt/msa/pssp/Useful_Resources/5

Answer (score 0):

I make some directories in a web project, as follow:
**Documents/WhitePaper/Resources/PDF**
and put some documents there, **Word.doc, Excel.xls, PowerPoint.ppt**. now in grid view:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"  
Width="99%"> 
<FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" /> 
<RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" /> 
<Columns> 
<asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="Title"> 
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" Width="100px" /> 
</asp:BoundField> 
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Url"  
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}"  
DataTextField="Category" HeaderText="Category" /> 
</Columns> 
<PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" /> 
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" /> 
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" /> 
<EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" /> 
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" /> 
</asp:GridView> 

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [UsefulResources]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

the link in this grid view points to each files and on click, starts download target file.
Url field in database is like this:
***~/Documents/WhitePaper/Resources/PDF/test.pdf***